# External propane hose access method in outdoor kitchen

Tags: kitchen-counters, propane, countertops, granite, kitchen-island

Building outdoor kitchen.  Plan to hook up two gas tanks with regulator w/ auto-changeover to three devices via a 3 way splitter.  Two appliances are built-ins connected internally (griddle, grill) and one permanent countertop pizza oven with hose connection on back. (Also would like to access non-permanent Wok burner from the front--but that can come out of a storage cabinet door). Kitchen will be constructed from metal studs, concrete backer board, stone veneer, and granite countertop.  It will be on a deck.

I've been trying to think through the best way to have a propane hose exit the inside of the outdoor kitchen and connect up to the pizza oven on the counter. I could:

- Exit from a hole in the granite countertop - but I have to find to waterproof it and get that extra cut
- Exit from underneath the countertop out of the back similar to a natural gas vent (see pic below). I would make it wider and run the hose out there.  I'm just worried that rain will find its way in there. It faces a windy side.
- same as above but with a waterproof 'in-use' access panel. I can't find any access panel that would be waterproof and allow for 'in-use' waterproof applications.  I suppose I may be able to install an 'in-use' weatherproof electrical box, but doubt it would look all that nice.

I do see that they have these types of cable pass-throughs.  I could go through the top of an electrical box and out through this and I would think it would be pretty waterproof. Right?

Any other ideas? As always: thanks for your time!

[image]

Example of second option:
[image: access idea]

Comment: It sounds as though you think your kitchen cabinets will be totally waterproof and that any possibility of moisture ingress will be fatal. You're building out of weather resistant materials, so if it does get a bit damp inside (which I think you should expect it to), it won't really matter. Just leave the bottom open to the deck so any water that does get in can drain out.

Comment: Not really. It's just about building it in a way that will last and is convenient for me. After 10,20,30 years galvanized studs, deckboard, cement backer can all show issues of repeated water intrusion.  More importantly: Ill have things inside (cooking ingredients/tools) which I'd rather avoid getting wet.  I can build a back wall out of cement and stone that has no intrusion, so *IF* there is a very simple solution it's 100% worth it to me. If not then I'll deal. It's a cost/benefit consideration and doesn't really have anything with an assumption of complete waterproof or water being fatal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up ordering a rubber grommet (grainger 3MPR5) and had the counter installers install a hole that the hose would go through and used silicone to seal it better.

[image: solution]

Answer (score 1):

Come through the wall of the counter with rigid plumbing, which I suspect is probably what you are doing on the other appliances. Then install a cut-off and convert to flexible hose outside the counter.

The rigid plumbing can be sealed however you like - you can install a flange, spray-foam, rubber gasket, whatever you think will make your installation water-tight. I'd suggest doing something to cover the hole, like installing a ledge or a blocking board (or brick?) to reduce direct spray/splash pressure. But make sure to leave plenty of airflow, and room to reach the cutoff valve.

Comment: That sounds like a good idea.  I just wondering what fitting should span the wall of the kitchen.  I could totally see how to do this with pvc, but with propane I'm out of my element. I just don't want leaks or make things not handle the pressure and be dangerous.  I'm more confident when I take hoses from manufactures than try and assemble something from a propane store.  If you have any tips there let me know.  I'll look around.

Comment: Oh yeah to be clear - the other appliances are hooked up INSIDE because they are builtins so all connections are internal.  But your idea of building some sort of ridge which doesn't allow rain intrusion is a good one.  I was looking for some product that does this already and all I could think about is 'in-use' electrical boxes and side-of-house dryer exhaust manifolds.  I could come down into an electrical box and out, but cant think of a decent faceplate that would support a propane hose

Comment: So @aghast would you say a black steel pipe used for gas lines with the right fittings on each side would be sufficient?  I assume it will need to be stainless steel to stand up to the weather.  Clearly I have a bit more research to look into.

Comment: @Joe Perhaps you have a local "outdoor living" or "patio living" type of store locally? They have probably run into customers with similar issues and might be able to provide ideas or referrals to people with experience. Also your local gas company might provide advice on materials and paint to prevent rust and damage to piping.

Comment: @Joe: You can find a couple of solutions to spanning the wall. But you say the wall is metal studs and concrete backer board - I'm not sure I'd have a lot of confidence in any attachment. I'd suggest you get some kind of solid material in to back the backer board in that area - maybe just a square of plywood - and use that to fasten your pipe. Have a search for "propane wall outlet" or "gas termination plate" to see some dedicated wall fixtures. Also, have a look at "floor flange" fixtures, which you might put in the wall.

Comment: Also, @Armand makes a couple of great points! Don't let materials worry you too much - the gas companies have some 20 year outdoor paint for their meters and such, which you can then paint over in whatever color you like (as long as it's "safety yellow" for gas ;-).